# how to stop loading feature on pressing back key

Tags: jquery

i have a login form, and am showing the loading icon for showing user veryfication....it does well, but when am in and press the back key, the loading icon is still there...so how can i make it disappear for good when am logged in.

this is my jquery code:

```
$(function(){

    $('.btn').click(function(){
        $('.load').show();

        });
    });
```

and here is my div in html

```
<div class="load" style="display:none;">
<img src="images/loading.gif"">Verifying user...</div>
```

so how can i do this...any help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have an AJAX call within the click() handler, right? What I would do then is,  at the success callback of the AJAX function - hide() the loader.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: i don have ajax call, what u see is only wat i got..so what shud i add??

Comment: So how then do you validate the user's credentials? Logging in is typically creating a session on the server - therefore you're typically going to call something on the server.

But OK - just hiding the thing is just adding $('.load').hide(); at the end of your method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keycode` to check whether user press `backspace` or not then hide your div:

```
$(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        $('.load').show();
    });

    $('body').keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 8){
            $('.load').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this works on pressing backspace on keyboard, but when i press back arrow on the browser the icon stil appear..so wat can i stop it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('.load').show();
});

$('body').keyup(function(e){
    var cc = (e.charCode) ? e.charCode : ((e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode);
    if(cc == 8){
        $('.load').hide();
    }
 });
});
```

Some browser support charcode some support keycode and some browser support which.

Keycode-IE, Chrome

which- Mozilla

charcode- safari

Comment: this works on pressing backspace on keyboard, but when i press back arrow on the browser the icon stil appear..so wat can i stop it?

Comment: Browser back arrow can not handle by this. And I think you can not handle it.